# How to add PHP code in WordPress comment form?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a custom PHP code :

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>
```

in the comment form section in the WordPress.

This is my comment form

```
<?php comment_form(array('label_submit' => 'Post Review')); ?>
```

Comment: I think your question is incomplete, your code is not showing

Comment: not showing my code.. what happens?

Comment: I want to add a custom php code :  "  <?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?> in the comment form section in the WordPress.

This is my comment form <?php comment_form(array('label_submit' => 'Post Review')); ?>

Many thanks for your valuable answers

Comment: This should give you hint http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/08/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of [useful action hooks](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L2131), `comment_form_top` and `comment_form`:

```
add_action( 'comment_form_top', function(){
    echo '<h1>Top</h1>';
});


add_action( 'comment_form', function(){
    echo '<h1>Bottom</h1>';
});
```

[image]

<sub>There's also `comment_form_before`. It appears before `<hr /><h3>Leave a Reply</h3>`.</sub>

Comment: Like the fine print, hahaha. +1 for the answer though

Comment: @PieterGoosen, this is the issue http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199889/imgur-medium-images-with-too-much-compression ;)